# Vim - permit quitting with new modified files

Tags: vim

The default behavior of Vim seems to be that `:q` will raise an error if the buffer is modified, and `:q!` will quit the buffer even if modified.  I would like to change the behavior of `:q` so it will only raise an error if the buffer is modified AND is associated with an existing file.  In other words, if a new buffer was created (e.g. by `:new` or by `:e nonexistentfile.txt`) and was modified without being written, I want `:q` to discard the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to create scratch buffers.

```
command! Scratch new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
```

Just issue `:Scatch` to create a scratch buffer

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I wanted.  For anyone else who's curious, check out `:h special-buffers`.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically make buffers with no backing files not prompt to save (and buffers with backing files will continue to prompt):

```
augroup nofilename_nofile
  autocmd!
  " Don't prompt for saving buffers with no file
  autocmd BufEnter * if eval('@%') == '' && &buftype == '' | setlocal buftype=nofile | end
augroup END
```